# Porting from Qt4to Qt5, Qt::WA_PaintOutsidePaintEvent no longer exist

Tags: qt, qt5, qwt, setattribute, paintevent

When porting from Qt4 to Qt5, there is a class GraphWidget, which inherit from class QWidget.

```
m_plot = new QwtPlot(this);  
ui->verticalLayout->addWidget(m_plot);
……
m_directPainter = new QwtPlotDirectPainter(m_plot->canvas());  
m_plot->canvas()->setAttribute(Qt::WA_PaintOutsidePaintEvent, true);
……
m_directPainter.drawSeries(……);
```

The Attribute `Qt::WA_PaintOutsidePaintEvent` does not exist anymore.
What should I do to make m_directPainter work properly?

As I learned from Qt5 documents, should I implement `paintEvent()` function, and call the `painter` there?

Answer (score 1):

`Qt::WA_PaintOutsidePaintEvent` was introduced to allow porting Qt3 programs to Qt4. Qt4 widgets should paint only from `paintEvent()`, thus in Qt5 the attribute was removed (good idea!). So you should transfer all painting code to a derived `paintEvent()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Qt::WA_PaintOutsidePaintEvent has only an effect in combination with the X11 paint engine that has been removed with Qt5. So you can simply remove the line as it has no effect with Qt5 ( or with Qt4, when not running the native graphicssystem ).

Without this flag QwtPlotDirectPainter uses a slightly less efficient path to draw incrementally, but also avoids running into the full repaints you have to do when moving your code into the paintEvent.

Comment: Actually I have to correct myself: the X11 paint engine has been reintroduced with Qt 5.10 and can be made effective by export QT_XCB_NATIVE_PAINTING=1.But as Qt::WA_PaintOutsidePaintEvent has not been reintroduced you need to modify the code of qwt_plot_directpainter.cpp manually to take the more efficient rendering path.